# how to insure that user's input is an integer or not

Tags: c++

```
short howMany=0;

cout<<"How many student grade details you want to calculate"<<endl;
cin>>howMany;

// now, here how can I check that user's input is integer or not?
```

Comment: The user's input is **not** an integer. It's a sequence of characters. The question is whether that sequence of characters can be **converted** to an integer value. Don't skip that conversion step when you're thinking about input.

Answer (score -1):

> now, here how can I check that user's input is integer or not?

```
if(!(std::cin >> howMany))
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to read or parse 'howMany'").
```